# Machine learning algorithm for ranking

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, xgboost, ranking

I am working on a ranking question, recommending k out of m items to the users. The evaluation metric is [average precision at K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Precision_at_K).

Both R and Python have [xgboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgboost) can be used for [pairwise comparison](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/rank) and can be adapted for ranking problems.

Are there other algorithms or approaches that can be applied to ranking problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem sounds like the classical top-N personal recommendation to me. There're lots of possibilities in the literature, for example:

- User-based collaborative filtering
- Content-based collaborative filtering
- Matrix factorisation

You'll need to read the literature and figure out which one is better for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get started with "**learning to rank**" , there are three solutions to deal with ranking problem .

1. **point-wise** , learning the score for **relevance** between each item
   within list and specific user is your target . This can be accomplished as recommendation do .
2. **pair-wise** , learning the "**relations**"  between items within list ,
   which respectively are beat loss or even , is your goal .
3. **list-wise** , learning the "**effectiveness**" of specific ranking list
   for items is your object .

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to recommend a list of ranked items to a user?

Take a look at collaborative filtering which is one of the most commonly used technique for recommender systems.

For python, [Pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) is something you can look at. [This link](https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/building-a-recommender-with-apache-spark-python-example-app-part1) contains some example how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Item Rank](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/IJCAI/2007/IJCAI07-444.pdf). It's a very simple algorithm which is used for ranking and cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Mahout is an open-source library that provides a good recommendation engine. I've used it on two projects successfully.